# How do I get rid of spacing between tabs in Android application?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 4 tabs that I load using a TabHost and TabWidget using the following layout:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" 
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:src="@drawable/titlebar" />
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#AAAAAA" 
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp">
            <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:tabStripEnabled="true" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="0dp" 
            android:layout_margin="-5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

This looks great in my emulator and also great on my friends G2, however on my EVO 4G there is weird spacing between each tab.  It looks like 5 or so pixels between each of the 4 tabs I load.
Again, in an emulator that has the exact same resolution of the EVO (800x480) it looks fine, no spacing between tabs.
Why does it look different on my EVO?
I've tried everything I can think of to get rid of the spacing, and nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set background color for tabwidget. see following function for example.

```
    public static void setTabColor(TabHost tabhost) { 
        for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++){ 
     tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff383737")); //unselected 
    } 
    tabhost.getCurrentTabView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffe9e8e8"));
}}
```